# Probability of difference 5 in pairs of random chosen numbers

Tags: probability

So here's a problem I saw:

> Six distinct positive integers are randomly chosen between 1 and 2006, inclusive. What is the probability that some pair of these integers has a difference that is a multiple of 5?

Can someone help me with it? I'm bad at probabilities. :(

Comment: @5xum Not sure this is relevant at all (or "simpler").

Comment: @OP "I'm bad at probabilities." Good news: these are not needed to solve this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just like [every other question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/338209/blastzit?tab=questions), you show no effort whatsoever in attempting to answer it on your own. Asking 'Can anyone help me with it?' is simply not enough.

Answer (score 2):

When a number is divided by $5$, the remainder can takes value from $0$ to $4$.

Hence, for 6 number, by pigeonhole principle, two of them will share the same remainder, $r$.

Let the first one be $5k_1+r$ and the second one be $5k_2+r$. Subtract them and you should observe something.